# JavaScript not working on any browser on my machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

This issue has been driving me crazy!
I am relatively new to web design. I started to learn coding on codecademy.com. Everything worked perfectly! html, css and JavaScript went smooth. However, this is not the case when I start coding with Sublime Text or DreamWeaver on my machine. Whenever I try to run my website, the scripts that I linked doesn't work. I copy-pasted the codes from a Codecadamy tutorial(html, css, JavaScript) into a completely new file in DreamWeaver(index.html, stylesheet.css and script.css), I did this to make sure my code isn't faulty. When I ran the code in the built-in Codecadamy browser, it works perfectly. But whenever I save the files with DreamWeaver or sublime text, the website seems to "ignore" the external .js file.. I tested the website on 4 different browsers(Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera) but found no luck!

I have no idea what might be causing this problem..

I tried to copy my code into the built-in Codecadamy but it still didn't work

Heres my simple javascript code(just to test out whether its working on my machine):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openDialog').click(function() {
        $('.container').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Here is my website, I hosted it in a public folder on my DropBox account;
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33331786/xbox/index.html

Comment: What does the error console/firebug say?

Comment: what is `container` is this some kind of `ID` or `Class` ?

Comment: Show the bit of HTML where you are including this JavaScript in. If it is in an external file you may simply be linking wrong.

Comment: @MohammadAdil #openDialog is a button to toggle visibility of .container(a <div> which holds some elements(img's, p's))

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie

<head>
 <title>This is a webpage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" ></link>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='global.js'></script>
<head>

Comment: @borislemke .. then have you tried `$('.container')`  , see an extra `.`

Comment: @MohammadAdil sry for the typo, in my .js file it is actually '.container' instead of 'container'

Comment: Also, is the global.js file in the same location as the html file? Try putting a simple alert("hello"); in the JavaScript and see if it runs.

Comment: @MohammadAdil yes, it is in the same location as the .html file. I took a look at koenp's answers. I have to add that I am running the html file locally with Chrome, so this may be the problem why my machine wont run the javascript due to security concerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your browser's JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined                           global.js:2
```

This is your source code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='global.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

You are trying to use jQuery **before** you load it!

Comment: Correct. Also, your script tag needs to begin with `//ajax.....` or `https://ajax.....`, not `http://ajax.....`, so that the script is loaded over HTTPS instead of HTTP when your site (i.e. Dropbox) is being accessed over HTTPS. Otherwise it will be blocked.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I didn't realize that the order was so important, so foolish of me..
Well, I was just a graphic designer before, will make sure to pay more attention to these details..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a local running server or are you using the file:// 'protocol' in your URL's? If you're not running a server then that 's the problem. Because of security constraints browsers do not run local JS files except when you explicitly enable the browser to do so.

See here for more info on how to do that: [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)

Comment: I opened the .html file with Google Chrome(and any other browsers I have), so yes, I am using the fil://'protocol'. I will review the link you've given and come back to you in a moment.. Thanks

Comment: I tried the solution but it didn't make any changes. Here I hosted my files into my DropBox account.. The site is up and running, but the .jc is still not working..

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33331786/xbox/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever reference the jQuery library? You could do it like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't help. But still thanks!
Heres a link to my website I hosted on my dropbox account;

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33331786/xbox/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I placed this command after linking my external .js file that confuses the browser because it is called before $ is defined..