# Does the same origin policy allow you to use ajax to request the current file with the file:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, same-origin-policy

If I have an html page I'm loading at the path `file://some/path/whatever.html`, can javascript in that file download `whatever.html` and examine it? I know the same origin policy disallows access to other files, but I'm not clear on whether it also bars access to the current file when using the `file://` protocol.

In short: does the same origin policy disallow any access to file:// protocol paths?

I looked at [mdn's documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs), but it doesn't make it clear.

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: see this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode

Starting chrome with allow file access from files will allow you to make ajax request to local files

Comment: @admdrew When I tried it I got a readyState 4 and status code 0. However, it does not generate the 'Script error.' `window.onerror` call I'm using to seeing with failing cross-domain ajax calls.

Comment: use sync ajax for local files: no latency anyway...

Comment: @Geoff448 I'm not actually trying to allow this to happen. My goal is actually to detect cross-domain policy violations before they're executed with ajax so i can avoid those annoying and mostly useless window.onerror calls.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser.

I've been able to do this in Firefox (using AJAX with jQuery, there might be an easier way), but not in Chrome, which doesn't allow access to local files to JavaScript.

**EDIT**: just learned that you can launch Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` parameter, which should enable this behavior.

Comment: i was able to ajax(location.href) in chrome from a desktop file just now (without any param)...

Comment: @dandavis that's odd, it didn't work for me a few days ago. Maybe I did something else wrong or differently. I'll check my script.

Comment: I'm not actually looking to enable this behavior, just want to understand the same origin policy more precisely. I just tried in latest version of firefox tho, and it doesn't seem to allow access either. Would have surprised me if it did.