# Writing to a file in Javascript using FileSystem Api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write to local file system using FileSystem API in Chrome. I am getting the following error while executing

> FileError is deprecated. Please use the 'name' or 'message' attributes of DOMError rather than 'code'.

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

var fs = null;

function errorHandler(e) {
  alert("hi");
  var msg = '';
  switch (e.code) {    //Error is being reported here
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  }
}

function onInitFs(fs) {
  alert("hi");

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log('Write completed.');
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
      };

      // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
      var blob = new Blob(['Add some text'], {type: 'text/plain'});

      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}

function initFS(){
  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}

if (window.requestFileSystem) {
  initFS();
}
```

And since i know the execution goes to `errorHandler` method i assume i am doing something wrong while calling the `requestFileSystem()` method. I would really appreciate help here. Thanks in advance

Further research shows that it fails with security error. How do i basically bypass that

Comment: In my Chrome that's not an error but a warning and onInitFs() is called (at least i get the alert). Anyway, as the message tells you, you shouldnt use FileError itself; furthermore, the whole FileSystem API you're using is ['abandoned'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) and works only with Chrome. Instead, use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to access local files.

Comment: @Bewusstsein onInitFs() is not called . It terminates with ErrorHandler method

Comment: @Bewusstsein While it's true that the FileSystem API is abandoned elsewhere, File API is in no way a replacement. They have very different roles.

Comment: @Bewusstsein Furthermore, the API is explicitly referenced from Chrome Apps docs as a method of file storage.

Comment: @user3851662 right, i thought your problem was the warning you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing the script locally (via file:///) you'll need to launch Chrome with the '--allow-file-access-from-files'-flag like so:

```
C:\Path\To\Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode), [source](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/)

If you're doing this within a Chrome app you'll need to add fileSystem-permissions to your manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "...",
    "version": "...",  
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "fileSystem": ["write"]
        }
    ]
}
```

[source](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)

To remove the warning you're getting simply use `e.name` and/or `e.message` instead of `e.code`:

```
function errorHandler(e) {
    alert(e.name + ": " + e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your errorHandler wasn't doing anything with msg anyway.  Try this:

```
function errorHandler(e) {  console.log("ERROR!: name: [" + e.name + "] message: [" + e.message + "]");  }
```