# How to use window.requestFileSystem of FileSystem API?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written below code in javascript:

javascript code:

```
var fs=null;

        function initFS() {
            window.requestFileSystem =window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
               window.requestFileSystem (window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {
                fs = filesystem;
            }, errorHandler);
        }
```

html code:

```
<input type="button"  id="button2" name="click" value="show" onclick="initFS();" />
```

but after clicking on show button in `initFS function`, after line `window.requestFileSystem (window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {`
it is showing error as "uncaught type error". Is there  any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can not define errorHandler

```
var fs=null; 


        function initFS() {
            window.requestFileSystem =window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
               window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {
                fs = filesystem;
                console.log(fs);
            }, errorHandler);
        }
        function errorHandler(e) {
           console.log(e); // it show everything that you want 
          }
```

Comment: @Shikha: can you tell what console print

Comment: Console prints "FileError is deprecated. Please use the 'name' or 'message' attributes of DOMError rather than 'code'

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930403/writing-to-a-file-in-javascript-using-filesystem-api may be it helps instead of FileError use name and message attributes

Comment: -I have done as per given link by you but still the type error is coming. Is any other solution?