# Using AngularJS with Oracle Apex

Tags: angularjs, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I was wondering if anyone who uses AngularJS with Oracle Apex could recommend some resources or tutorials on integrating the two please?

I have found a Dan McGhan presentation and a Codersaurus video but unfortunately these don't go into sufficient detail to start me off.

Any help or advice would be gratefully received.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm about to try this myself as a little project at home. In theory it should be fine since AngularJS is designed so that it can be used as part of an existing web page. Having said that, I'm not totally convinced that AngularJS and Apex is a great combination! If I get something done in the next couple of weeks, I'll stick a blog up about it and let you know.

Comment: Out of interest, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this and what do you know about Angular already? I ask because I've successfully implemented an Angular app in an Apex web page, but I've not gotten any further than getting some simple two-way data binding working. For example, would you be looking to have Angular speak to an Apex web service directly or are you just looking to manipulate data that is already available to the client? Do you care about how to architect this properly or do you just want to see it working?

Comment: Hi @Drumbeg, thanks for getting back to me.  This is something my boss mentioned an interest in; using AngularJS to make up for some of Apex's shortcomings as an alternative to using jquery.  I admit to knowing nothing about Angular at this stage, I was just looking into whether this is a feasible/worthwhile combination to pursue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search gave me this [Guide from Dan McGhan](http://nyoug.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/McGhan_AngularJS.pdf). In part 3 he shows a nice way how to embed the neccessary files, even that you will need to take care of the [allow-file-access-from-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) property.