# Chrome load local resource

Tags: google-chrome, file-access

I want to use a local JS file for development reasons but run into "Not allowed to load local resource"-error in chrome (Version 41.0.2272.89). I read a lot of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode), but this:

```
"C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

does not work for me on my testpage https://jsfiddle.net/sreL1nge/, even that chrome://version says:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

Can someone try wether it works for him on the testpage? Any alternative ways to access a local file without setting up a local server?