# Access local files from locally running http server

Tags: python, web

I want to access files in my local machine by using urls. For example "file:///usr/local/home/thapaliya/constants.py". What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about enabling access to local files via HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple HTTP server:

```
  python -m http.server 8000
```

Or for Python 2:

```
  python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Answer (score 0):

I copied from [orszacky's answer for the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/5595995):

A little http server locally.

For Windows, the easiest is to install http-server globally using node's package manager:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Then simply run http-server in any of your project directories:

```
C:\my_project> http-server
```

You can also use Python in Windows, and follow the instruction below:

For Linux, since Python is usually available in most Linux distributions,

```
run python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

in your project directory, and you can load your page on `http://localhost:8000`

In Python 3 the SimpleHTTPServer module has been merged into http.server, so the new command is

```
python3 -m http.server.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. keep the files in a some folder which you want to access from a localhost
2. In command prompt go to that location and type
   python -m http.server 8080
3. now type localhost :8080 in browser you will able to access files in that folder
4. if u want to use some js files for paticular html files then
   `<script src="http://localhost:8080/main.js"</script>`
   make sure you run this program on another port

Answer (score 0):

Had the same need and have been searching for something simple but more versatile than python's built-in HTTP server (which is meant for debugging only and can't do range requests, i.e. doesn't handle streaming video properly).

Ended up writing a simple Web UI wrapper for [caddy2](https://caddyserver.com/v2) which relies on caddy's ability to return directory listings as JSON so the entire logic is browser-side. The main intent is to support audio/video playing in one frame while browsing related HTML/PDF or text in another split frame (there is some simple mapping with regexes for matching multimedia files with the related text files).

- https://github.com/glowinthedark/mediabro4caddy

> <sup>The old and currently [unmaintained version](https://github.com/glowinthedark/pymediacenter) is using python's built-in HTTP server which was extended to support range requests.</sup>