# jquery.get only working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website, and I need to access a file called `friends.txt` and get the first element.

I then use it in the folder name to display some pictures. The problem is that `jquery.get` seems to have security restrictions and I can only get it to work in Internet Explorer. Should I do something else to read a server side file?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get("friends.txt", function(data){
        var text = data.split("/");
        var p1 = text[0];
            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute("src", "../../Documents/dumpster_shit/FB/"+p1+"/0.jpg");
            x.setAttribute("class","democlass")
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use relative path?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode

Comment: Are you running this by viewing the file or by looking at it through `localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a minor correction (I removed an extraneous brace) you code works fine as it is on Chrome.

Proof:  http://sam.nipl.net/test-friends.html ,
http://sam.nipl.net/friends.txt

Are you trying to test it locally on your own computer, using a `file:///` URL?  Some browsers have security features to prevent you accessing local files using ajax.  For Chrome, you need to use this command line option:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

You could also try running your test site in a local web server.