# How to save file locally in Apache Cordova using file plugin

Tags: cordova

I am trying to save a file locally using Apache cordova file plugin and I am getting a Security Error

My code is below

```
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
    console.log("got main dir", dir.name);
    dir.getFile("catalog.json", {create:true}, function(file) {
            console.log("got the file", file);
            logOb = file;
        });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error.name);
  });
```

Error on the console:

```
It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.
SecurityError
```

Do I need to add in allow-intent tags to enable working with files?

I think I am obviously missing something but I have tried searching on Internet without concrete results.

Comment: On what platform are you running the app?

Comment: I am running it on browser

Answer (score 2):

Cordova mobile webviews have, by default, local file access enabled (but always ruled by the application configuration). Regular browsers have many security features enabled: one of this is the block of local file access from other files (e.g. js code).

A common source of error is the missing `--allow-file-access-from-files` launch parameter for Chrome. See [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) for more information about this.

Be sure to check the Cordova file plugin [browser quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#browser-quirks) also.

Another problem with your code is the use of `cordova.file.dataDirectory`  shortcut that, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files), isn't not supported in the browser:

> cordova.file.dataDirectory - Persistent and private data storage
>   within the application's sandbox using internal memory (iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10, windows)

If you look at the `cordova.file.*Directory` list, you can see that the *browser platform* doesn't support any cordova shortcut.

Depending on the browser you're using, a path like `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/file` or `file:///persistent/path/to/entry` should be used in the browser. You can find more information about this in the [browser quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#browser-quirks) section of the documentation.

Comment: can you elaborate on "If you look at the `cordova.file.*Directory` list". What list are you referring to?

Comment: @Chase Cordova [URLs to important file-system directories list](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files). At the end of each list element there is a list with platforms where it's available: the browser platform doesn't appears in any list.

Comment: Wow.... I feel so stupid. In my head I wasn't separating the "Windows" OS from the browser (I'm on Windows / Chrome). I realize now they're referring to actual Windows native apps. So, right you are. Browser isn't listed anywhere. But, I've tried `filesystem:file:///persistent/`, `filesystem:http://localhost:8080/persistent/`, `"filesystem:" + cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "persistent/"` (which returns the former)... but I can't shake this security error. Also running chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to save a file localy when using

```
 cordova build browser
```

with Chrome and Edge, but not with Firefox.

Thanks to the former comments I did understand, that `cordova.file.dataDirectory` is not supported by `platform browser`. After some digging I found out [that in Chrome you need to use the webkit functions to access local files](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit/).

```
 window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT|window.TEMPORARY , [filesize], [ReadWriteFunction]);
```

However for all other platforms (including Firefox) we can use `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. In order to have a code that is applicable for all cases (android, ios, browser (with Chrome and Firefox)) we need to use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` or when neccessary `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`. With this information the code of the question could be changed to.

```
 // Function when Folder is loaded
 successFunction = function(dir){
      console.log("got main dir", dir.name);
      dir.getFile("catalog.json", {create:true}, function(file) {
           console.log("got the file", file);
           logOb = file;
      });
 };
 
 // Function for error
 errorFunction = function(error){
      console.log(error.message);
      console.log(error.name);
 }

 if(cordova.platformId === 'browser'){
      if(typeof window.webkitRequestFileSystem !== 'undefined'){
           window.webkitRequestFileSystem(
                window.PERSISTENT , // Where to look for
                1024*1024, // request max available size ( here 1 MB), 
                function(dir){ successFunction.apply(this, [dir]); };
                function(error){ errorFunction.apply(this, [error]); };
           });
      }
 }
 
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
      cordova.file.dataDirectory, 
      function(dir){ successFunction.apply(this, [dir]); };
      function(error){ errorFunction.apply(this, [error]); };
 });
```

I did not check if the code of the question is running like this.