# how to Include local .html files, with diffrent dir, into local .html project with JQuery or AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

So im making a project for my self.

Right now, im having a simple `index.html` page, with some design, and it gets some info from an API, and  display it with angular. This works just fine.

But i have another dir(folder) called `follow` that contains another .html file, with some animated html(JQuery UI), that i want to show on the `index.html` file in the root. Not just the code, but as preview, like normal html pages. How is this possible?

I've tried using the `ng-include`, on a div, but doesnt work. I've tried JQuery's `.load()` function, but that complains about `cross-domain` even when its all local.

Here's come of the things i've tried:

```
<div ng-include="'notify/followers-notification.html'"></div>
...
<div id="teest"></div>
...
$( "#teest" ).load( "notify/followers-notification.html" );
...
```

**Edit**
This is what im getting in the console, from JQuery:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console, what is not working? Is the page not loaded?

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 i've updated the post, with some info, right now angular is having some trouble for some reason. Im gonna try debug it, and see if i can get something out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-view and ng-include make ajax requests to serve the template file. Because you're running it locally, it can't make that request. An easy fix around this is to use [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) to serve your contents over a local server.

If you don't want to use server then one workaround is to inline your templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sample.html">
  <div>This is my sample template</div>
</script>

<div ng-include src="'sample.html'"></div>
```

This puts your template into Angular's template cache.  When an ng-include directive is processed, Angular checks the cache first.

Comment: I've been thinking on a server, and using nodejs, but no. I want it to run local, without a server or anything, just call a API, and CDN for css and js etc.. and just have it all in "one file".. And it must be possible to be able to include the second html file, into the index, and see the angular js like in the index file.. hope that made sense

Answer (score 0):

It's because browsers (Chrome at least) don't allow AJAX requests on local environment, you need some kind of server, or to run chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag.

[How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)