# AngularJS Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error in browser "

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector>/modulerr?

My Script app.js

```
    var sampleApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/AddNewOrder',{
             templateUrl:'view/add_order.html',
             controller:'addOrderController'
    }).
        when('/ShowOrders',{
            templateUrl:'view/show_order.html',
             controller:'addOrderController'
    }).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/AddNewOrder'
    });
});


`SampleApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$location){
       $scope.setRoute = function(route){
           $location.path(route);
});`
```

And HTML code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
  <head>

    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
          padding-top: 10px;
          background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <ul class="nav">
                <li><a data-ng-click="setRoute('AddNewOrder')"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a data-ng-click="setRoute('ShowOrders')"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div data-ng-view></div>
        </div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Dont no why this error is comming. Needs your suggestion to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I looked at your stacktrace, It seems like you're loading you JavaScript files from folder path directly where it asking for a file using `file` protocol. To fic this issue you have to host you files/folder on some server like IIS,Lamp, Wamp,etc(any server) & then access html from hosted link ( http://localhost:8080/index.html )

Though if you don't want to host files you could enable direct file access you can refer [this answer](
[How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode))

---

You should be injecting `ngRoute` module in `myApp` module, because the routing API doesn't come up with out of the box with `angular.js`. It has been there in `angular-route.js` which keep its API in `ngRoute` module. Basically whenever you wanted to use Routeing API you should be injecting `ngRoute` in your application module. The other thing I want to make sure is, `angular-route-min.js`(I guess you have it in `js/route.min.js` by renaming it) loaded correctly or not.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: please explain why so he know that.

Comment: @MrJSingh thanks for heads up, I updated the answer :)

Comment: @PankajParkar I injected 'ngRoute' in by 'myApp' module but I am getting the same error again.

Comment: Have you check angular-route.min.js loaded on page?

Comment: I am new in angularJS. Can you tell me how to check it

Comment: Np, first tell me what js/route.min.js does have?

Comment: it has angular-route-min.js which is downloaded from Angular.org

Comment: OMG. I saw you error stack.. it seems like you haven't hosted your project folder.. I'd say put these file on hosted folder like lamp, wamp or IIS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120899/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-pankaj-parkar).