# How can I restore permissions for Chrome to access any local files from VS Code?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

Now, every time I try to open my html file in my Chrome browser, I get this message:

> ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Can someone please tell me how I can reverse this?

How do I grant Chrome the permission to access any local files on my VS Code and atom?
Now, Thanks to Kuma, check out the thread link he or she provided, which helped me. You just have to go to system preferences, and under security and privacy, go to filers and folders, and go to files and folders and check the check box next to chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, you can try the following:
Run the the following command on the file in a terminal, then try to open it again:

```
xattr 'your .html file name'
# If it shows com.apple.quarantine, run
xattr -c 'your html file name'
```

If that fixes it then it's most likely some apple security metadata on the file that get attached when files are downloaded from the web.

If you are on Windows10, you can view all the permissions you have added and rejected for an app (see this link: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/368598/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-windows-10/amp/)

Extract:
From the Settings screen, you can head to Settings > Apps > Apps & Features, click an app, and click “Advanced Options.”
Scroll down, and you’ll see the permissions the app can use under “App Permissions.” Toggle the app permissions on or off to allow or disallow access.

Otherwise, knowing what OS you are using will help find a solution.

There is also this other stack overflow thread, so you can try some of the answers there: [Can't open some html files in chrome (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482690/cant-open-some-html-files-in-chrome-mac)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, I am using Mac OS Big Sur. The "your" as in real "your" for my html file name I just saved it as index.html

Comment: Could not create temporary directory: Permission denied

Comment: THis is what I got back.

Comment: You need to go to the folder where it is saved (in your terminal) then run the command: xattr index.html