# angular-cli build without a webserver

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Last week I started building a portfolio website using Angular 2 created with Angular-Cli. This portfolio website is a school assignment.

one of the end requirements is that the website can run without a webserver.

When I open the website on a webserver (after building it with `ng build`) I have no problem at all loading it. But  when I open it locally in the browser I receive 404 file not found on each javascript file.

These javascript files are in the same directory as the index page shown below.

[image: Files are in the same directory]

This is my index.hmtl generated by `ng build`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hallo, ik ben Maarten.</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the files aren't found when opening the index file in the browser.

[image: 404 - files not found]

Is it possible to run a Angular 2 project build with Angular-Cli without a webserver?

Thanks,

Maarten Paauw

Comment: What's the reasoning behind it being able to run without the server?

Comment: The reason why is because the website will be archived so in the future someone could look it up and use it without any extra program, like a web server. A strange rule on a ICT-educational institution. But I can't do anything about that.

Comment: This is your browser stopping the files from loading locally because of security reasons.

If you are using chrome you could do something like this: 

    "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files



But I don't how viable that is at your institution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18587027/1754020

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files are failing to load because of the `<base href="/">` tag. It rewrites all `file://` requests, so they start referencing files that do not exist.

The ng-cli provides a [`--base-href` configuration option](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml), which can be set to `./`, so that the links continue working:

```
ng build --base-href "./"
```