# jQuery load() function does not load to Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery

The jQuery `load()` function does not load to Chrome or Firefox, but it worked in Atom's HTML preview?

How can you set the `--allow-from-local-files` option in Google Chrome?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test2").click(function() {
    $(".test1").load("data.html");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test2">click here</div>
<div class="test1">
  This will disappear after clicking on ....
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any AJAX in there. `.load()` has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: @Difster yes it does; `load()` makes an AJAX request to retrieve text/html

Comment: You're right. I never thought of it as an AJAX function. I guess I just saw it line an include file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)