# ReactJS: render with ReactJSX syntax on javascript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepath

I want to use JSX syntax on render, but it is not recognized if I try to use it on `.js` file.

It does render using object notation though.

Using this:

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style media="screen">
      .demo {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="js"></div>
<div id="react"></div>
<div id="react2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="react-demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now **react-demo.js** file:

```
(function(){
"use strict";
/* global React ReactDOM*/
const render = () => {
const jsContainer = document.getElementById("js");
jsContainer.innerHTML = `
  <div class="demo">
    Hello JS
    <input>
    <p>${new Date()}</p>
  </div>
`;
const reactContainer = document.getElementById("react");
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "demo" },
        "Hello React",
        React.createElement('input'),
        React.createElement('p', null, new Date().toString())
    ),
    reactContainer
  );
  ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello Here</p>, document.getElementById('react2'))
}
setInterval(render, 1000)

})();
```

When I run it, I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
And it points to this line: `ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello Here</p>, document.getElementById('react2'))`

Now I read I need to change script type to `text/babel`. But doing that gives me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/oerp/js-programs/react-demo/react-demo.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

But I'm merely loading local file. Why does it work that way with babel type?

Though I was able to use JSX syntax directly on html like:

```
<script type="text/babel">

  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('react2')
  );

</script>
```

But I do want to put rendering on `js` file, not on `html` file.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx ?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue with babel type is that it can't be used locally using `file` type. It has to be from allowed types only, like `http`, `https`, `data` etc.

So the simplest approach would be to create local http server (to serve related html and js files). Like:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

And then this works:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="react-demo.js"></script>`

Then I can use `text/babel` using specified file instead of just using it directly on html.

P.S. [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) answer by `orszaczky` helped me solve this.

Answer (score -3):

Use type babel for react script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="react-demo.js"></script> - native javascript

<script type="text/babel" src="react-demo.js"></script> - it`s react js
```

Comment: OP has indicated they did that. The issue is the loading of a local file via xhr, which needs to be explicitly allowed.

Comment: No, the OP explicitly states they used the type. The error message is also quite clear-loading a local file via xhr requires a flag in Chrome (don't know about other browsers). OP's code shows the type is set to what you've suggested.