# Swagger-editor local installation not working

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm trying to set up swagger-editor locally. 
After cloning, I ran it using `npm start` but it never works on the browser .
and the browser  gives the error:

> This page isn’t working localhost sent an invalid response.
>   ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

My nodejs version is 10.16.1 and npm version is 6.9.0.

Does it work only with 6.x version of nodejs? Did I miss anything here?

Or is there any other tool for setting up swagger-editor locally or using it?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Or is there any other tool for setting up swagger-editor locally or using it?"* See [Swagger Editor offline installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47164114/113116)

Comment: @Helen I have already tried it, but it does not work.