# How to validate openapi 3.0.0 yaml spec?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I have a yaml specification that has been updated from swagger 2.0 to openapi 3.0.0

The file itself is about 7,000 lines so it is challenging to validate by hand.

I need to figure out which tags I have are no longer compatible with openapi 3.0.0. How can I validate my schema? Are there any command line tools I can use?

I do not want to copy/paste this code somewhere online because I don't want to expose all the routes publicly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Swagger Editor

https://editor.swagger.io performs validation on the **client side**, meaning your definition is not sent anywhere. You can also [run the editor locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164178/113116), e.g. offline.

Notes:

- Because of lazy loading you may need to expand all operations and models in the UI panel to see all of the errors.
- Warnings are displayed as gutter icons, apart from the error list.

#### Other validators

https://openapi.tools has a list of [OpenAPI validation tools](https://openapi.tools/#description-validators), including command-line tools and Node.js modules.

Answer (score 3):

[Vacuum](https://quobix.com/vacuum/) is a nice fast command line tool for openapi spec validation.

Once you have it installed, linting is as simple as:

```bash
$ vacuum lint -d my-openapi-specification.yaml
```

(`-d` means *details* - print out found issues)

Answer (score 3):

https://openapi.tools is where I'd go to find OpenAPI validation tools

Answer (score 2):

Use openapi-lint extension on visual studio code and remember to name your file as `*openapi.json, *openapi.yaml, *openapi.yml, *oas3.json, *oas3.yml, *oas3yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

I use [swagger-cli](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli). It's a validator and bundler that supports `$ref` among other things.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate the swagger-cli into spring boot app and trigger the validation on build?

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI Generator CLI tool, which is widely used, also offers schema validation.

### Docker

To validate a schema using Docker, you can run the following command:

```bash
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli validate \
    -i /local/file.yaml
```

### Shellscript

Alternatively, you can use the shell script provided in the OpenAPI Generator repository:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/bin/utils/openapi-generator-cli.sh

```bash
./openapi-generator-cli.sh validate -i file.yaml
```

For more information on how to use OpenAPI Generator CLI, you can refer to the documentation at: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage