# API documentation using swagger, YAML syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, swagger

I am learning API documentation using swagger (open API version 3)

I am trying to document the post route.

Here is my YAML syntax.

```yaml
/**
 * @swagger
 * /home: 
 *  post:
 *      summary: create a new product
 *      tags: [Products]
 *      requestBody:
 *          required: true
 *          content:
 *              application/json:
 *                  schema:                 
 *                      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
 * 
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: The product was inserted successfully
 *              content:
 *                  application/json:
 *                      schema:
 *                          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
 *         500:
 *              description: Some server error
 * 
 */
```

I have thoroughly gone through this code. Yet, I keep running into this error:

```
Here's the report:


 Error in ./routes/route.js :
YAMLSyntaxError: All collection items must start at the same column at line 3, column 6:

     summary: create a new product
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^…
```

Comment: Pay attention to spaces. Some of your indentations have different number of spaces than other. E.g. 200 has longer indentation than 500. Probably in many other places as well. These have to be aligned.

Comment: @freakish YAML error messages are really not helpful to beginners. It doesn't point you to the error. The error messages are vague and don't show you what you are missing. Do you have any linter you can suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend using this [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).
Using it you may find that you are just missing indent(s) before `500:` in `responses:`

[image]

Changing the script to something like this should solve your issue:

```
    responses:
        200:
            description: The product was inserted successfully
            content:
                application/json:
                    schema:
                        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
        500:
            description: Some server error
```

Comment: YAML error messages are really not helpful to beginners. It doesn't point you to the error. The error messages are vague and don't show you what you are missing

Comment: I haven't tested most of the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216133/how-to-validate-openapi-3-0-0-yaml-spec) myself, but I believe that they are worth checking.