# Develop ES6 modules with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

As Chrome supports EcmaScript 6 modules now ([Medium article](https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7)), I thought I could develop a demo app using the `export` and `import` syntax. However, this only works when uploading my code to a server - which is quite annoying when developing. Other developers have faced similar problems and recommend using Chrome with `--disable-web-security` ([Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)) or `--allow-file-access-from-files` ([How to launch html using Chrome at “--allow-file-access-from-files” mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)). However, I now get the error

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced
>   for module scripts per HTML spec.

And I can't seem to find a way to turn off Strict MIME type checking in Chrome (my version is 64.0.3282.140).

So, this is **my question**: How can I develop ES6 modules locally with Chrome (this must be possible, surely)?

Comment: Just use a local development server...?

Comment: Yes, I could, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: That *is* the simple way.

Comment: Okay. But I still think it should be possible to just test your code locally without using a development server. I'll do it, though, if there's no other way.

Comment: I didn't say there isn't another way.  I said there's no simpler way.  Just use NodeJS to serve your site.  It's *far better* than serving files locally.

Comment: Have a look at [`lite-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) install it globally and run it in the root of your project. That should be good enough as a local server with auto reload.

Comment: There are enough server packages available (I am using `http-server` right now), it's really no problem to run one. I just wanted to know if there's a way without using a development server.