# Javascript- <iframe> isn't working with local file

Tags: javascript, file, iframe

I'm trying to display a local file in my computer using `<iframe>`. If I add the file as an existing item to my project it works great but if I add the path of my local file (to `<iframe>` src) it doesn't work. I tried creating the file as txt file and as html file and both don't work. I also tried different methods to write the path (single or double slash and backslash). the first `<iframe>` in the code is the one that works with the existing file(added to the project) and the second one is the one with the path to the file location in my computer(which doesn't work).

After debugging the javascript part I saw that the second file's body (`pa.contentWindow.document.body`) doesn't include `childnodes[0]` in his properties like the first file does, and it made me understand that maybe the program thinks that the file is empty or undefined which is also the error I get:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference).

What can I do? Any help would be appreciated.

html:

```
 <iframe id="50" src="file.txt" style="width:100px;height:100px; border:0; border:none;">Browser doesnt support iframe</iframe>
 <iframe id="51" src="file:///C:\folder\file.txt" style="width:100px;height:100px; border:0; border:none;">Browser doesnt support iframe</iframe>
```

javascript:

```
 oFrame = document.getElementById("50");
        strRawContents = String(oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
 pa = document.getElementById("51");
        strRawContentspa = String(pa.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)?

Comment: I've used IE so far, thank you for your comment

Comment: Wait! The parent page is hosted on a web server, and you want to access your local file system? That's not going to work because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). It is a security feature with no workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the iframe has been loaded before to do something with it:

```
oFrame.onload = () => {
  // your javascript actions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the frames source comes from different origin than your main document - you won't have access to it.
[MDN article on origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Imagine a site which opens you banks site in an iframe and just grabs your account data from the dom.

Comment: So do you have an idea for another way to read this file from my local disk? Thanks for commenting