# import not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I am creating an single page app in vanilla JavaScript. I want to organize my code in different files to make it modular, which means I should be able to access functions defined in one file in another file. I am using ES6 native `import` `export` for this:

file-1.js:

```
export function func1() {}
export function func2() {}
```

file-2.js:

```
import { func1, func2 } from './file-1';
```

index.html:

```
<script src="file-1.js"></script>
```

When I run index.html in Chrome (version 65), I get the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

What's wrong in my code? Chrome 65 fully supports ES6 module system.

Comment: `import { func1, func2 } from './file-1';` you missed a dash

Comment: It was a typo. Corrected here. I have mentioned the file name correctly in my actual code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a working example

**file1.mjs**

```
function log1() {
  console.log('log1');
}
function log2() {
  console.log('log2');
}
export { log1, log2 };
```

**file2.mjs** you must explicitly write `.mjs` extension

```
import { log1, log2 } from './file1.mjs';

log1();
log2();
```

**index.html** Notice attribute **type="module"**

```
<body>
    <script type="module" src="file2.mjs"></script>
</body>
```

Then you need a static server to get rid of CORS block.

```
$ yarn global add serve
$ serve ./
```

Finally go to `http://localhost:5000` and it will work

Update: [It is recommended to use `.mjs` file extension for modules instead of `.js`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#mjs)

Comment: Where is the actual CORS happening here? I have everything from your answer, except the last part (static server) and I don't even see request for my module (file2.js) happening at all.

Comment: Something has changed inside Chrome, now it doesn't even notify the CORS block in the console tab anymore. I'm not sure but maybe Chrome's file:// protocol has some specific rules so that the requests were not shown in the Chrome Dev Tools. But you should always use a local server to work with Javascript on the browser so you can replicate a real website while developing.

Comment: Using a server the "import" syntax indeed does work. Thanks. Where do you think CORS happens in the above case?

Comment: As I said, in some previous versions of Chrome, it used to explicitly notify problem in ***CONSOLE*** tab when using `file://` protocol.

Comment: You don't need to use .mjs extension as you mentioned in the edit. I'm doing it on chrome with .js using a server. Regarding CORS, I see now the articles that "file://" protocol can cause CORS issues on some browsers. Unfortunately if CORS indeed is a problem, it's a pitty there is no more warning in the console.

Comment: Got the same issue. Including type=' module' such an important thing to get it work, start a local server to use http:// protocol rather than file:// one cuz the CORS policy blocking your file from executing in Chrome v70+ `Access to script at 'file:///*.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Answer (score 4):

Chrome (v70) has some kind of issues when working with `import` syntax on the local files served using `file` protocol. It is probably CORS blocking that can happen using `file` protocol according to some articles. But Chrome also does not show CORS warning in the console in this case - which is strange. Therefore some kind of HTTP server is needed so the files are served via HTTP protocol (as Vu showed in his answer). Firefox v63 (probably >v60) doesn't have these issues and you can compose `html` with `js` modules using `file://` protocol without a special server.

Also make sure to:

- use file type extensions when importing (`import { func1, func2 } from './file-B.js';`).
- use `type="module"` in html `script` element (`<script type="module" src="file-A.js"></script>`)

Comment: Actually we can ignore browser CORS policy like this [How to launch html using Chrome at “--allow-file-access-from-files” mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) @croraf