# Run JavaScript file from another JavaScript file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Everyone,

I am trying to run one javascript file from another javascript file in html.

The first Javascript file is "cfPayout.js"

Code:

```js
class cashfreeUser {

  constructor() {
    this.clientId;
    this.jsonresponse;
    this.clientSecret;
    this.token;
    this.expiry;
  }

  clientAuth(clientId, clientSecret, stage)

  {

    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    this.stage = stage;
    var linkAuthorize;

    if (stage == "TEST") {
      linkAuthorize = "https://payout­-gamma.cashfree.com//payout/v1/authorize";
    } else if (stage == "PROD") {
      linkAuthorize = "https://payout­-api.cashfree.com//payout/v1/authorize";
    }

    var request = require('sync-request')

    this.jsonresponse = request("POST", "https://payout­-gamma.cashfree.com//payout/v1/authorize", {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-Client-Id': clientId,
        'X-Client-Secret': clientSecret
      }
    });
    var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if (data["status"] == "ERROR") {
      return data["message"].toString();
    }
    this.expiry = data["data"]["expiry"];
    this.token = data["data"]["token"];

    return this.token;
  }

  expiryCheck() {

    var expirytime = this.expiry;
    var currenttime = ((new Date).getTime()) / 1000;
    //checks if the token will expire in the next minute and generates a new one 
    if (expirytime - currenttime <= 60) {
      var temp = new cashfreeUser;
      return temp.clientAuth(this.clientId, this.clientSecret, this.stage);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  addBeneficiary(beneId, name, email, phone, bankAccount, ifsc, address1, address2, city, state, pincode) {

    if ((beneId == null) || (name == null) || (email == null) || (phone == null) || (address1 == null)) {
      return "Mandatory paramters missing";
    } else {
      var userParam = {
        "beneId": beneId,
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
        "bankAccount": bankAccount, //optional
        "ifsc": ifsc, //ptional
        "address1": address1,
        "address2": address2, //optional
        "city": city, //optional
        "state": state, //optional
        "pincode": pincode //optional
      }

      var temp = new cashfreeUser;
      temp.expiryCheck();
      var token = this.token;
      var linkAddBeneficiary;
      if (this.stage == "TEST") {
        linkAddBeneficiary = "https://payout­-gamma.cashfree.com/payout/v1/addBeneficiary";
      } else if (this.stage == "PROD") {
        linkAddBeneficiary = "https://payout­-api.cashfree.com/payout/v1/addBeneficiary";
      }

      var headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
      }


      var request = require('sync-request')
      this.jsonresponse = request("POST", linkAddBeneficiary, {
        json: userParam,
        headers: headers,
      });
      var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
      data = JSON.parse(data);

      return data;

    }

  }

  getBalance() {
    var token = this.token;

    var header = {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
    }
    var temp = new cashfreeUser;
    temp.expiryCheck();
    var linkGetBalance;
    if (this.stage == "TEST") {
      linkGetBalance = "https://payout-gamma.cashfree.com/payout/v1/getBalance";
    } else if (this.stage == "PROD") {
      linkGetBalance = "https://payout-api.cashfree.com/payout/v1/getBalance";
    }


    var request = require('sync-request')
    this.jsonresponse = request("GET", linkGetBalance, {
      headers: header,
    });
    var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    return data;
  }

  requestTransfer(beneId, amount, transferId, transferMode, remarks) {
    if ((beneId == null) || (amount == null) || (transferId == null)) {
      return "Mandatory paramters missing";
    } else {
      var userRequestParam = {
        "beneId": beneId,
        "amount": amount,
        "transferId": transferId,
        "transferMode": transferMode, //optional
        "remarks": remarks //optional
      }
      var token = this.token;

      var temp = new cashfreeUser;
      temp.expiryCheck();

      var headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
      }
      var linkRequestTransfer;
      if (this.stage == "TEST") {
        linkRequestTransfer = "https://payout-gamma.cashfree.com/payout/v1/requestTransfer";
      } else if (this.stage == "PROD") {
        linkRequestTransfer = "https://payout-api.cashfree.com/payout/v1/requestTransfer";
      }

      var request = require('sync-request')
      this.jsonresponse = request("POST", linkRequestTransfer, {
        headers: headers,
        json: userRequestParam
      });
      var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
      data = JSON.parse(data);

      return data;
    }

  }

  getTransferStatus(transferId) {
    if (transferId == null) {
      return "Mandatory paramters missing";
    } else {
      var token = this.token;
      var temp = new cashfreeUser;
      temp.expiryCheck();
      var headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        'transferId': transferId
      }
      var linkTransferStatus;
      if (this.stage == "TEST") {
        linkTransferStatus = "https://payout-gamma.cashfree.com/payout/v1/getTransferStatus" + "?transferId=" + transferId;
      } else if (this.stage == "PROD") {
        linkTransferStatus = "https://payout-api.cashfree.com/payout/v1/getTransferStatus" + "?transferId=" + transferId;
      }

      var request = require('sync-request')
      this.jsonresponse = request("GET", linkTransferStatus, {
        headers: headers,
      });
      var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
      data = JSON.parse(data);

      return data;

    }
  }

  bankDetailsValidation(name, phone, bankAccount, ifsc) {
    if ((name == null) || (phone == null) || (bankAccount == null) || (ifsc == null)) {
      return "Mandatory paramters missing";
    } else {
      var token = this.token;
      var temp = new cashfreeUser;
      temp.expiryCheck();
      var headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        'name': name,
        'phone': phone,
        'bankAccount': bankAccount,
        'ifsc': ifsc
      }
      var linkBankValidation;
      if (this.stage == "TEST") {
        linkBankValidation = "https://payout-gamma.cashfree.com/payout/v1/validation/bankDetails" + "?name=" + name + "&phone=" + phone + "&bankAccount=" + bankAccount + "&ifsc=" + ifsc;
      } else if (this.stage == "PROD") {
        linkBankValidation = "https://payout-api.cashfree.com/payout/v1/validation/bankDetails" + "?name=" + name + "&phone=" + phone + "&bankAccount=" + bankAccount + "&ifsc=" + ifsc;
      }

      var request = require('sync-request')
      this.jsonresponse = request("GET", linkBankValidation, {
        headers: headers,
      });
      var data = this.jsonresponse.body.toString('utf-8');
      data = JSON.parse(data);

      return data;

    }

  }

}

module.exports = cashfreeUser;
```

And second Javascript file is"execute.js":

```js
const user = require('./cfPayout.js');

let user2 = new user;
console.log(user2.clientAuth('CF154780PZJOCY38FMQMAI', '2719af34b7834b3e40d558d9a2b49a0e1658d62e', "PROD"));
user2.expiryCheck();
console.log(user2.addBeneficiary('JOHN180121', 'john doe', 'johndoe@cashfree.com', '9876543210', '00091111202233', 'HDFC0000001', 'vpa', 'ABC Street', 'add 2', 'Bangalore', 'Karnataka', '560001'));
user2.requestTransfer('JOHN18011', '100', '76723288672267867867', 'banktransfer', 'optional');
user2.getTransferStatus('76723288672267867867');
user2.bankDetailsValidation("Joh", '9910115208', '00011020001772', 'HDFC0000001');
user2.getBalance();
```

Here what i have tried.
HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Payment Gateway</title>
  <script src="cfPayout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="execute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(user2.clientAuth('CF154780PZJOCY38FMQMAI', '2719af34b7834b3e40d558d9a2b49a0e1658d62e', "PROD"));
    user2.expiryCheck();
    console.log(user2.addBeneficiary('JOHN180121', 'john doe', 'johndoe@cashfree.com', '9876543210', '00091111202233', 'HDFC0000001', 'vpa', 'ABC Street', 'add 2', 'Bangalore', 'Karnataka', '560001'));
    user2.requestTransfer('JOHN18011', '100', '76723288672267867867', 'banktransfer', 'optional');
    user2.getTransferStatus('76723288672267867867');
    user2.bankDetailsValidation("Joh", '9910115208', '00011020001772', 'HDFC0000001');
    user2.getBalance();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately its not working. Can anyone help me to figure this out and run this two Javascript file, one from another, in HTML.

Thank you.

Comment: `its not working` - check the browser developer tools console for errors - please report all errors you see *in the question* - at least then we'll know what 'it's not working' means

Comment: You need to remove the excess code from both the `.js` files, only keep the code which would be necessary enough to understand the question.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718855/import-not-working-in-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To your first javascript file add this:

```js
var script2 = document.createElement("script");
script2.setAttribute('src', 'link to script');
document.getElementById("id of element in html file").appendChild(script2);
```

Comment: Post JavaScript (and other languages) in codeblocks, not a blockquote, For JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, you can go one step further and use the script editor.

Comment: Ok! @Samathingamajig