# Javascript D3 not showing visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to replicate the visualization I see on this github profile

https://github.com/mojoaxel/d3-sunburst/tree/master/examples

I copied the following code and changed the path to the respective files.

suburst.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sequences sunburst</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sunburst.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css"/>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="sunburst.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="sunburst-breadcrumbs"></div>
      <div id="sunburst-chart">
        <div id="sunburst-description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <input type="checkbox" id="togglelegend"> Legend<br/>
      <div id="sunburst-legend" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var sunburst = new Sunburst({
          colors: {
            "home": "#5687d1",
            "product": "#7b615c",
            "search": "#de783b",
            "account": "#6ab975",
            "other": "#a173d1",
            "end": "#bbbbbb"
          }
        });
        sunburst.loadCsv("/Users/Documents/data/visit-sequences.csv");
        d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", function() {
          var legend = d3.select('#sunburst-legend');
          if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
            legend.style("visibility", "");
          } else {
            legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
          }
        });
      })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**sunburst.js**

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['d3'], factory);
  } else {
    root.Sunburst = factory(root.d3);
  }
}(this, function (d3) {

  var defaultOptions = {
    // DOM Selectors
    selectors: {
      breadcrumbs:  '#sunburst-breadcrumbs',
      chart:        '#sunburst-chart',
      description:  '#sunburst-description',
      legend:       '#sunburst-legend'
    },

    // Dimensions of sunburst.
    width: 750,
    height: 600,

    // Mapping of step names to colors.
    colors: {},

    // If a color-name is missing this color-scale is used
    colorScale: d3.scale.category20(),
    colorScaleLength: 20,

    // Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
    breadcrumbs: {
      w: 75,
      h: 30,
      s: 3,
      t: 10
    },

    // parser settings
    separator: '-'
  };

  /**
   * This hashing function returns a number between 0 and 4294967295 (inclusive) from the given string.
   * @see https://github.com/darkskyapp/string-hash
   * @param {String} str 
   */
  function hash(str) {
    var hash = 5381;
    var i = str.length;
    while(i) {
      hash = (hash * 33) ^ str.charCodeAt(--i);
    }
    return hash >>> 0;
  }

  var Sunburst = function(options, data) {
    this.opt = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);

    // Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
    this.totalSize = 0;

    if (data) {
      this.setData(data);
    }
  }

  Sunburst.prototype.getColorByName = function(name) {
    return this.opt.colors[name] || this.opt.colorScale(hash(name) % this.opt.colorScaleLength);
  }

  Sunburst.prototype.setData = function(data) {
    var json = this.buildHierarchy(data);
    this.createVisualization(json);
  }

  Sunburst.prototype.loadCsv = function(csvFile) {
    // Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
    // row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.
    d3.text(csvFile, function(text) {
      var array = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
      var json = this.buildHierarchy(array);
      this.createVisualization(json);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  // Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
  Sunburst.prototype.createVisualization = function(json) {
    var that = this;
    var radius = Math.min(this.opt.width, this.opt.height) / 2


    this.vis = d3.select(this.opt.selectors.chart).append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", this.opt.width)
      .attr("height", this.opt.height)
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("id", "sunburst-container")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.opt.width / 2 + "," + this.opt.height / 2 + ")");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
      .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
      .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
      .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    // Basic setup of page elements.
    this.initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
    this.drawLegend();

    // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
    var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
        return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

    var all = this.vis.data([json])
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter();

    all.append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return that.getColorByName(d.name); })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", that.mouseover.bind(this));

    // some tests with text
    /*
    var arcText = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
      .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y * 0.4); })
      .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy * 0.4); })
    var arcsText = arcs.append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", arcText)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("id", function(d, i){
        return "s" + i;
      });
    var texts = all.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", "0")
      .attr("dy", "0")
      .style("text-anchor","middle")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i){
        return "#s" + i;
      })
      .attr("startOffset",function(d,i){return "25%";})
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.depth === 1 ? d.name : '';
      });
    */

    // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
    d3.select(this.opt.selectors.chart).on("mouseleave", that.mouseleave.bind(this));

    // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
    var node =  all.node();
    this.totalSize = node ? node.__data__.value : 0;
  }

  // Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
  Sunburst.prototype.mouseover = function(d) {

    var percentage = (100 * d.value / this.totalSize).toPrecision(3);
    var sequenceArray = this.getAncestors(d);

    this.updateDescription(sequenceArray, d.value, percentage)
    this.updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, d.value, percentage);

    // Fade all the segments.
    this.vis.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

      // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
    this.vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
        return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
      })
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }

  // Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
  Sunburst.prototype.mouseleave = function(d) {
    var that = this;

    // Hide the breadcrumb trail
    d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

    // Deactivate all segments during transition.
    d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

    // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
    //TODO cancel this transition on mouseover
    d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
        d3.select(this).on("mouseover", that.mouseover.bind(that));
      });

    d3.select(this.opt.selectors.description)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
  }

  // Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
  // nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
  Sunburst.prototype.getAncestors = function(node) {
    var path = [];
    var current = node;
    while (current.parent) {
      path.unshift(current);
      current = current.parent;
    }
    return path;
  }

  Sunburst.prototype.initializeBreadcrumbTrail = function() {
    // Add the svg area.
    var trail = d3.select(this.opt.selectors.breadcrumbs).append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", this.opt.width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
      // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
    trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
  }

  // Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
  Sunburst.prototype.breadcrumbPoints = function(d, i) {
    var points = [];
    var b = this.opt.breadcrumbs;

    points.push("0,0");
    points.push(b.w + ",0");
    points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
    points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
    points.push("0," + b.h);
    if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
      points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
    }
    return points.join(" ");
  }

  // format the description string in the middle of the chart
  Sunburst.prototype.formatDescription = function(sequence, value, percentage) {
    return percentage < 0.1 ? "< 0.1%" : percentage + '%';
  }

  Sunburst.prototype.updateDescription = function(sequence, value, percentage) {
    d3.select(this.opt.selectors.description)
      .html(this.formatDescription(sequence, value, percentage))
      .style("visibility", "");
  }

  // format the text at the end of the breadcrumbs
  Sunburst.prototype.formatBreadcrumbText = function(sequence, value, percentage) {
    return value + " (" + (percentage < 0.1 ? "< 0.1%" : percentage + "%") + ")";
  }

  // Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
  Sunburst.prototype.updateBreadcrumbs = function(sequence, value, percentage) {
    var that = this;
    var b = this.opt.breadcrumbs;

    // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
    var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(sequence, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

    // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
    var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

    entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", this.breadcrumbPoints.bind(that))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return that.getColorByName(d.name); });

    entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
    g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
    });

    // Remove exiting nodes.
    g.exit().remove();

    // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
    d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (sequence.length + 1) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .html(this.formatBreadcrumbText(sequence, value, percentage));

    // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
    d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

  }

  Sunburst.prototype.drawLegend = function() {

    // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
    var li = {
      w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
    };

    var legend = d3.select(this.opt.selectors.legend).append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(this.opt.colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

    var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(this.opt.colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
      });

    g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

    g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
  }

  // Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
  // for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
  // root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how
  // often that sequence occurred.
  Sunburst.prototype.buildHierarchy = function(array) {
    var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var sequence = array[i][0];
      var size = +array[i][1];
      if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
        continue;
      }
      var parts = sequence.split(this.opt.separator);
      var currentNode = root;
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        var children = currentNode["children"] || [];
        var nodeName = parts[j];
        var childNode;
        if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
          // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
          var foundChild = false;
          for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
            if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
              childNode = children[k];
              foundChild = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
          if (!foundChild) {
            childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
            children.push(childNode);
          }
          currentNode = childNode;
        } else {
          // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
          childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
          children.push(childNode);
        }
      }
    }
    return root;
  }

  return Sunburst;
}));
```

All the html, js and css files are stored in same folder.

But when I run it, I get the browser window like this with no visualization but just a legend box on the right.

[image]

What am I missing? The dataset is downloaded from the same github page.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: the path that you are loading the csv from, looks incorrect. are you on windows ?

Comment: Ok so I tried running a local webserver using node.js. And then run the html file. But I still get the same output

Answer (score 1):

Provided the path to `visit-sequences.csv` is correct, its local loading will be blocked by the browser ([see CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)).

You can either:

- run it via a (even local) webserver
- start Chrome  with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag (if you're using Chrome)

Comment: Yes, here is what it looks like in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587027/2898738

Comment: Ok it says use local webserver instead of doing chrome as it exposes the machine documents to get accessed. When I run a web server and get a localjost:8080, how do I then run this html script so that it works on that server? Just double click the html script and it will open on that server?

Comment: No, you have to put files in a directory the webserver is allowed to read (sometimes named www). This depends on the webserver configuration.

Comment: if I run that node.js code in the directory where all my files are it will start a webserver in that directory. Now how do I run the html file then?

Comment: You may hit using http://localhost:8080/<basedir_if_any>/sunburst.html.
Also, if you use a webserver, you have to change the `loadCsv` path to target a relative path. (=> `sunburst.loadCsv("visit-sequences.csv");` if you put it in the same directory)

Comment: As suggested by SO, this discussion is quite beyond the scope of the original problem. Although I'm glad to help you, please consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if you're satisfied with the answer of the main issue.

Comment: I did the local web server thing and still get the same output

Comment: There might be other errors unrelated to this security issue (which would have blocked you anyway). Have you got a console output?

Comment: It is working for me with the following files in the same directory (accessed via a webserver): examples.css, sunburst.html, sunburst.js, visit-sequences.csv, and using `sunburst.loadCsv("visit-sequences.csv");`

Comment: I wrote another question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381808/running-html-javascript-file-from-a-local-node-js-webserver

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
sunburst.loadCsv("/Users/i854319/Documents/Mike_UX_web/data/visit-sequences.csv");
```

Your browser cannot just load a file from your PC.

Comment: Not sure why is that happening? How to fix it?