# Angular build empty project

Tags: angular, ng-build

Create a simple project in angular7.
Its working fine with in development mode.

after completing, build through `ng build --prod` command.

Its generate **dist** folder with `index.html` with assets and some `JS files`

Check index file

[image]

If open in browers, its just white screen.

any solution what I am missing.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^7.2.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No-error, just blank white browser screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming it is because the browser attempts to access the local files and this throws an error to your console. You cannot directly serve by opening the `index.html` since file access is restricted.

You can however create a static server using `lite-server` or use some `chrome extension.`

[try this : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb ]

Another alternative is to modify the browser target shortcut and add `--web-security-disabled --allow-file-access-from-files` flags

Read more : [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)

Comment: thanks buddy, Using Chrome extension and its working.

Comment: Anytime! Happy to help.

Comment: Do consider an upvote and you can accept the best answer for future reference

Comment: upload the whole files to domain(xyz.com) for testing purpose in 3 level of folders  (xyz.com/f1/f2/f3/app), but again its not working. 
When I checked sourcecode and see the files, its loading from path (xyz.com/runtime.js). I am wondering why?

Answer (score 1):

You always need a server to run angular project. When you are running `ng serve` angular internally creates one server which is called `localhost`.

You can use any local server like `iis` to run the project.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use with `xampp` you need to change `base href` in `index.html` in `dist` folder.

**STEP:1**
copy `app2` folder generated inside `dist` and paste it in `xampp/htdocs`

**STEP:2 - xampp/htdocs/app2/index.html**
change `<base href="/">` into

```
<base href="./">
```

**STEP:3** open browser and navigate to `http://localhost/app2`

Comment: I try XAMPP but still same issue.