# AJAX call towards local storage

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have tried to read a simple text file, whose URI is C:\reading.txt, in my computer through AJAX:

```
fetch("C:/reading.txt");
```

Web browser throws an exception during test of above statement and says:

> Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/reading.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app.

I have tried this in Firefox, Chromium and Internet Explorer. All of them gave similar messages. Accessing local storage via AJAX may be dangerous, but I am just developing an offline application. Could we pass this restriction?

**Protest against closing...**

The application told here is not a network application. Thus, we can not apply HTTP on application layer. To do this the application must be published in a server technology like IIS, Apache Tomcat, JBoss etc. [Pointed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local) mentions web based applications, so it does not answer my question.

Comment: If you’re developing an off-line application; don’t build it around a traditional web browser. Use something like Electron instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should start your browser with a specific flag to override the above security measure (https://cmatskas.com/interacting-with-local-data-files-using-chrome/):

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-file (for Windows)
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args  --allow-file-access-from-file (for MacOS)
```

Comment: I had following command run in order to start Chromium based Microsoft Edge: `msedge.exe --allow-file-access-from-file` Yet, nothing is different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode

Comment: I thank you dear companion. I have found a solution in the thread. On the other hand, a similar security adjustment ought to be in Firefox based systems. I hope I can learn it too.